# How to use Bootstrap-3-Typeahead work with embe-data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My ember version:

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
Ember             : 2.11.0
Ember Data        : 2.11.1
jQuery            : 3.1.1
Ember Simple Auth : 1.2.0
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

Before I use `ember data`, I have a component like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.TextField.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    var _this = this;
    this.$().typeahead({
      source: function(query, process) {
        $.getJSON("/api/" + _this.get('modelName'), {query: query, access_type: 'typeahead'}, function(data) {
          process(data);
        });
      }
    })
  },

  willDestroyElement: function() {
    this.$().typeahead('destroy');
  }
})
```

Use this component:

```
{{typeahead-input type="text" modelName='shipping_spaces' value=shippingSpace class="form-control"}}
```

And this component work with `Bootstrap-3-Typeahead`(https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead).

But when I use `ember-data` to my project, I did not know how to use `Bootstrap-3-Typeahead` work with `ember-data`. Because all data came from `this.store.query('order')`, not use `ajax` any more.

So if I must use `typeahead`, I must design a `addo`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the content of the search function. The search function has a second argument `process` as the callback function. Call it when you receive the result from store.

Here is an example:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.TextField.extend({
  store: Ember.inject.service(),

  didInsertElement: function() {
    var _this = this;
    this.$().typeahead({
      source: function(query, process) {
        this.store.query('order', query).then(function(data){
          process(data);
        });
      }
    })
  },

  willDestroyElement: function() {
    this.$().typeahead('destroy');
  }
})
```

Alternative 2:

Now you may think that injecting `store` to a component is bad. It depends! If this is an *order-querying component*, it is ok. But if you really don't want to inject store to a component, just use a closure action.

Example for closure action:

```
didInsertElement: function() {
  var _this = this;
  this.$().typeahead({
    source: function(query, process) {
      let remoteFunc = this.get('remoteCallFunc');
      remoteFunc(query).then(function(data){
        process(data);
      });
    }
  })
},
```

And usage is:

```
{{typeahead-input type="text" remoteCallFunc=(action 'retrieveShippingSpaces') 
    value=shippingSpace class="form-control"}}
```